# postgres create temporary table in function is slow

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, temp-tables

I am facing a strange problem. in PostgreSQL, I want to create a temporary table in a function. Using below statement to create:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytemp ON COMMIT DROP
    AS SELECT empid, sal, myfunction(empid,sal) FROM emp;
```

When I run this by itself, it takes 28 seconds. But when I put it into function code, it takes 3 minutes. I have verified the timing by displaying `clock_timestamp()` before and after the creation statement. The part of the function is:

```
begin 
    /*..... other code lines...*/
    v_select:='select empid, sal, myfunction(empid,sal) from emp';
    raise notice '%','time - '||clock_timestamp();
    execute 'create temporary table mytemp on commit drop as '||v_select;
    raise notice '%','time - '||clock_timestamp();
    /*..... other code lines...*/
end;
```

it takes 3 minutes to execute. Please help me, I am keen to know the reason for such a difference.

Comment: Temporary table is going to take 1.5 MB in size. My temp_buffer is set to 8MB and work_mem='128MB' for the session.

Comment: Did you try it several times to make sure it is not because of caching issues? You could use [`auto_explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) to get `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output fo both `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` statements and see where the difference is.

Comment: I had tried both the cases several times but the observation is same always. Could not try with clearing cache as there is no option in PostgreSQL of clearing cache at session level.